# True or false; If $R$ is a PID, then for any $R$-module $M$, any submodule of $M$ is cyclic

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, modules

True or false; If $R$ is a PID, then for any $R$-module $M$, any submodule of $M$ is cyclic.

I have been pondering for a while and cant decide to which side to choose, but in the end I sided with 'false'. With the following example

Take $R$ = $\mathbb{Z}$, $M$ = $\mathbb Z[x]$, and let $M$ be the trivial sub-module of itself. In this setting, $M$ is not even finitely generated.

So my question is, is my example valid, if not please point out my mistake (and perhaps provide a valid example).

Or if the statement turns out to be true, provide a proof ?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Your example is fine. Over a PID any submodule of a *cyclic* module $M$ is itself cyclic. When $M$ is not cyclic there's no reason for its submodules to be so either.

Comment: I see thanks for answering my follow-up question, I was going to ask if there is any 'patch' to make make the claim true if it turned out false.

Comment: There is a whole theory about finitely generated modules over PIDs, giving many more nice results that are very similar to the results the dimension of a vector space yields. The classification of such modules should be found in most books/courses about linear algebra, so if your question was from a class, look forward to it. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your example is fine; even if the question is interpreted as “every *proper* submodule is cyclic”, you could just consider the submodule $\mathbb{Z}[x^2]$.

There are simpler examples, though: $\mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z}\oplus\mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z}$ is a finitely generated counterexample also for the stricter interpretation.

Even simpler: take a three-dimensional vector space over a field (two-dimensional suffices for the non strict interpretation).